# Gradle: How to get a particular dependency RELEASE version number

Tags: gradle, maven-3, android-gradle-plugin

I have written a collection of sample Android apps that default to using the most recent version of a particular library using the syntax 4.0.+ which works quite well and can be overridden by the user using Gradle properties, fwiw.

I would like to report at build time and/or run time what actual version for the particular library is being used, e.g. 4.0.7.  Does Gradle have access to this actual version?  Failing that, is there a way to query a maven repository to obtain the RELEASE version number?

Answer (score 1):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task prepare << {
    configurations.runtime.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each {
        def vers = it.getModuleVersion().getId().getVersion()
        logger.lifecycle    "${it.name}  ${it.type} has version=$vers"   
    }
}

dependencies {
  runtime group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'
  runtime group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging',  version: '1.0.4', ext: 'jar'
}
```

You should be able to cut-paste the above build.gradle file and execute it.

You will need to substitute 'runtime' configuration with whatever configuration you are using in your 'dependencies'.     As FYI, I believe the 'runtime' configuration is added by the 'java' plugin.

Comment: When I added this snippet to the project configuration, Gradle complained that "Could not find property 'runtime' on configuration container."  Can you edit/elaborate on your answer to show how I should properly use it with a very simple example?

Comment: Perhaps you can post more of your gradle code and I could comment.   I struggled with the same issue for a long time until I found the above.